# Python and Structuring API calls

Tags: python, automation, get

I'm having some trouble with the responses I'm receiving after running a python script used to export files into a folder for automation purposes. The script should locate a file from our data center and then download that file into a folder. I plan to use windows scheduler to assist with automation portion whenever I have a working script.

I adjusted the parameters of the of the sample script (lines 8 through 20) that can also be found here (https://github.com/nrccua/file_export_sample/blob/master/file_export_sample.py).But when I run the script, I receive a "No files to download!" in the terminal. Is there something that I am missing here? I know that this is inaccurate because I'm able to see said files in our system. I've used both the "Delivered" and "NotDeliverd" parameters and still receive the same message in the terminal.

I tested pieces of the script and was able to login and authenticate successfully. So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Is there something else that needs to be added the script? I'm using VS code to test and there appear to be no problems or syntax errors in the workspace/acutal .py file.

API Documentation: https://helpcenter.encoura.org/hc/en-us/article_attachments/20370572326029

API Swagger: https://developers.encoura.org/

I was expecting to receive a a list of available files to download. Instead, I receive a message stating that there were no files to download.

```
import requests
import json
import os
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse, unquote
from pathlib import Path

# SET THE API URL
URL = "https://api.datalab.nrccua.org/v1"
# SET YOUR API KEY
API_KEY = "xxxx"
# SET YOUR ORG UID
ORGANIZATION_UID = "d1e01227-404d-439a-b7e8-12cfd11a6863"
# override this if you want
DOWNLOAD_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path(DOWNLOAD_DIR)
# SET USERNAME
USERNAME = "xxxx@mailbox.sc.edu"
# SET PASSWORD
PASSWORD = "xxxx"


def get_valid_filename(s):
    s = str(s).strip().replace(" ", "_")
    return re.sub(r"(?u)[^-\w.]", "", s)


# SET YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD
payload = {"userName": USERNAME, "password": PASSWORD, "acceptedTerms": True}

session = requests.Session()

# set the api key for the rest of the session
session.headers.update({"x-api-key": API_KEY})

# login
response_json = session.post(f"{URL}/login", data=json.dumps(payload)).json()

if "sessionToken" not in response_json:
    print(f"Couldn't find sessionToken in response json:\n {response_json}")

# set the authorization header for the rest of the session
session.headers.update({"Authorization": f"JWT {response_json['sessionToken']}"})

# payload to return list of files
get_exports_payload = {"status": "Delivered", "productKey": "score-reporter"}
response_json = session.get(
    f"{URL}/datacenter/exports", params=get_exports_payload, headers={"Organization": ORGANIZATION_UID},
).json()

# loop through results
files_to_download = []
for export in response_json:
    if "uid" in export:
        export_uid = export["uid"]
        # api route for download
        file_export_url = f"{URL}/datacenter/exports/{export_uid}/download"
        export_response_json = session.get(file_export_url, headers={"Organization": ORGANIZATION_UID}).json()
        if "downloadUrl" in export_response_json:
            files_to_download.append(export_response_json["downloadUrl"])

if len(files_to_download) == 0:
    print(f"No files to download!")
else:
    for file in files_to_download:
        parsed_url = urlparse(file)
        # get the file name from the url, unescape it, and then replace whitespace with underscore
        escaped_filename = get_valid_filename(unquote(os.path.basename(parsed_url.path)))
        download_path = DOWNLOAD_DIR / escaped_filename
        print(f"Downloading file from url {file}")
        # don't use the session here
        download_file_response = requests.get(file, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)
        if download_file_response.ok:
            print(f"Writing file to {download_path}.")
            with open(download_path, "wb") as f:
                # we are going to chunk the download because we don't know how large the files are
                for chunk in download_file_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    if chunk:
                        f.write(chunk)
        else:
            print(f"There was an error retrieving {file} with status code {download_file_response.status_code}.")
            print(f"{download_file_response.content}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear what the issue is exactly but I would probably start with making sure you're seeing the expected items by testing your API calls from the Swagger site itself.

The Swagger page lets you actually test API calls using your account, just select the **Authorize** button and put your creds in there:

[image: Screenshot of Encoura Swagger API documentation page with Authorize button highlighted]

You should test the `/datacenter/exports` and `/datacenter/exports/{uid}/download` API calls from there to make sure the returned data matches what you expect:

[image: Screenshot of Encoura Swagger API documentation page with Exports section shown]

If you notice issues, you can go from there.

If you see the data you're expecting, then you can go back to debugging your Python code. I would start debugging by simply adding a few `print()` statements in your loops, like so:

```
if "uid" in export:
    export_uid = export["uid"]
    print("#### Found uid:", export_uid)
```

...and:

```
if "downloadUrl" in export_response_json:
    print("#### Found download for uid:", export_uid)
    files_to_download.append(export_response_json["downloadUrl"])
```

...and:

```
# loop through results
files_to_download = []
print("#### response_json is length:", len(response_json))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the OpenAPI spec, you can setup the API in a tool like Postman or Insomnia to hit the API with different payloads and see what the response is. Try to download the file via Postman, and then you can compare the call Postman makes to the call your app makes to see if there is a difference.

Also, check if your user is authorized to view the file. It *may be possible* that your user credentials do not have the right to access the file, thus you don't get it back. This would be an authn/authz problem, where you are *authenticated* by the system, but not *authorized* to view the file